# How to stop car from slipping backwards on a slope?

Tags: unity, car

I am trying to simulate a car in Unity, the slope of the road is high so the car slips backwards. Is there any physics property which can stop this from happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the car resisting the backward force? Is it in drive, or are you trying to simulate a parking brake? How do you handle moving the car at the moment?

Comment: Have you checked out Physics Materials by any chance?

Comment: @DMGregory I am trying to simulate a parking brake, the car stops where it is suppose to and motortorque equals to zero but since the road has a slope, the car slides backwards.

Comment: Have you checked out all the properties in Rigidbody section of Unity? I think this page could just have what you're looking for by default: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.Sleep.html (if it does, please come back and write your answer so that we can upvote ;) ) Also see the Sleeping section in this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html

Answer (score 1):

When in park you could mark as kinematic, or a better solution may be increasing the angular & linear drag on the rigidbody to stop it from sliding.

That will also help if there was a collision to the car during runtime. it would drag along from the impact force rather than go flying off at impact speed.